# Contract not Compiling: Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, remix, compilation

I am just playing around on testnet w/ code snippets ...

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `_from` doesn't exist in the `burn()` function. If you mean to burn the balance of the person (or contract) making the transaction, substitute `msg.sender`.

It works as is in the `burnFrom` function because you're passing in the address `from` as a parameter.